# Iterparse object has no attribute next

Tags: python, memory, iterparse, celementtree

I am parsing a 700mb file, I have the following code with works fine on my test file without the line context.iter(context) and event, elem = context.next().

```
form xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
source = ("AAT.xml")
context = iter(context)
event, root = context.next()
for event, elem in context:
         if event == event("end"):
             some processing...
             elem.clear()
         root.clear()
```

However when I move on to iterparse the 700mb the file it still crashes out. Having read:

[Should memory usage increase when using ElementTree.iterparse() when clear()ing trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074200/should-memory-usage-increase-when-using-elementtree-iterparse-when-clearing)

I believe this is because I need to clear the root, however having followed a few tutorials which I have incorporated above I'm continually getting an error:

```
line 9, in <module>
event, root = context.next()
AttributeError: 'iterparse' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I'm still new to Python and I cannot work out why this is happening, as far as I can see I am in line with the examples.

Comment: You're missing the initial context = iterparse() call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python3, the iterator syntax is `next(context)` instead of `context.next()`